# How can I make all icons rotate individually instead of just one?

Tags: javascript

I have an svg icon that on click, I want it to rotate 180 degrees. Currently, only the first icon toggles the class, but I'm trying to get all icons to toggle.

**I'm not sure what I'm missing**...

```js
let accordionChevron = document.querySelector('.rotate');

accordionChevron.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('down');
})
```

```css
.rotate {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.rotate.down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="rotate" fill="none" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m0 2.82837 2-2 6 6 6-6 2 2-8 8.00003z" fill="#000a70"></path>
</svg>
<hr>
<svg class="rotate" fill="none" height="11" viewBox="0 0 16 11" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m0 2.82837 2-2 6 6 6-6 2 2-8 8.00003z" fill="#000a70"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+event+listener+for+all+elements+with+class) of [Want to add “addEventListener” on multiple elements with same class](/q/51573435/4642212).

Comment: I did not see that question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
let accordionChevronList = document.querySelectorAll('.rotate');
accordionChevronList.forEach(accordionChevron=>{
    accordionChevron.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('down');
    });
});
```